# Short-circuit evaluation and assignment in C++

Tags: c++

Is something like this possible in C++:

```
if (int* x = (foo() || bar()))
{
    // do something with x
}
else
{
    // do something else if both foo() and bar() return nullptr
}
```

I know the code will not compile (cannot convert bool to int*), but is there a valid equivalent "shortcut" code to be able to do this kind of shortcut? Basically, what I want is to assign to x the return value of foo() if foo() does not return a null pointer. If foo() yields a null pointer, then assign the return value of bar() to x.

Assume that foo() and bar() are expensive calculations, so need to minimize the number of calls to them. If foo() does not yield a null pointer, then ideally, there should be no need to call bar().

Comment: and what if bar() returns a nullptr ? You could use a function, you could use a ternery.

Comment: Did you try to compile it? Which compiler c or c++? Choose one, or ask independently.

Comment: You can do like this: `if ((x = foo()) || (x = bar())) {...} else {...}`

Comment: `if (int*x=[](int*p){return p?p:bar();}(foo()))`. (`<wink/>`)

Comment: Why not simply provide a function `int *foobar() {int *x = foo(); if (!x) x = bar();  return x;}` and then do `if (foobar()) ....` or `int *x = foobar(); if (x) ....`?    Practically, will often be easier to understand, therefore easier to get right and maintain, than attempts to squeeze multiple assignment of `x` into some statement.   Also meets requirement of minimising number of calls of `foo()` and `bar()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a [new C++17 feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html), the following should be possible:

```
if(int* x = foo(); x = x ? x : bar())
```

Pre-C++17 will require you to declare the x outside (below improving above by avoiding self-assignment; thanks, N00byEdge):

```
int* x;
if(x = foo(), x ? x : (x = bar()))
```

But then, probably moving the assignment outside is yet nicer:

```
int* x = foo();
if(x ? x : (x = bar()))
```

In all above cases, the compiler might warn you that you might have mixed up assignment with comparison (`=` instead of `==`); to make the compiler aware that assignment is intended, you can place additional parentheses around the assignments...

*Edit:* Nice solution, posted by [freestyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175117/freestyle), unfortunately only as comment (here, parentheses are *required* as assignment has lower precedence than logical or):

```
int* x;
if((x = foo()) || (x = bar()))
```

Which could look, assuming C++17, like this:

```
if(int* x; (x = foo()) || (x = bar()))
```

or refining my own answer based on:

```
if(int* x = foo(); x || (x = bar()))
```

Comment: On,  `if(int* x = foo(); x = x ? x : bar())`, wouldn't `if(int* x = foo(); x ? x : x = bar())` be nicer for no self-assignment of x?

Comment: @N00byEdge Absolutely true... Not too happy about the ternary anyway, *if* compressing that much at all, I personally prefer the `||` solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
int* y = foo();    
int* x = y == NULL ? bar() : y;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int * x{foo()};
if(!x)
{
  x = bar();
}
if(!x)
{
   // report error
}
// do something with x
```

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi This is "valid equivalent code" OP is asking for.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi This code is not "ugly" by any means. And the answer is "yes, you can do it".

Comment: Look [at this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506633/short-circuit-evaluation-and-assignment-in-c#comment86017586_49506633).

Comment: You totally miss what OP ask. OP clearly don't want that x exist if x is `nullptr`.

Comment: @Stargateur  OP explained rather clearly that he wants to avoid an expensive call to `bar` if `foo` returns a non null pointer. Nothing about preventing x from existing if functions return nullptr. In his example `x` also exists in `else` branch when it is nullptr.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi That would be the example of "ugly code".

Comment: @VTT "ugly" is purely subjective. As I understood the question, the example is what OP is looking for, no matter if *we* consider it ugly or not...

Comment: There is one reason I deleted the comment, and others.